# how to upload asp.net website on internet

Tags: asp.net, hosting

I have build a small asp website. And I have upload content on internet using Filezilla. But when I go to the website it gives me 'index of' and list of my webpages aspx and aspx.cs pages. So when I click on any it shows me the codes not the page.This is the first time I am doing it so please pardon and silly mistakes.

Thanks

Comment: You have to setup the website in IIS. you can ask your hosting provider to host the website.

Answer (score 0):

Have an index.aspx page as your homepage in the directory containing those files. This would prevent directory listing.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config, add the following

```
  <defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <add value="Index.aspx" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```